# Extracting image then thumbnail that image and display on index.html

Tags: python, django

So I made my mind to use python goose for extracting the main image when url is inserted. I found good example here https://blog.openshift.com/day-16-goose-extractor-an-article-extractor-that-just-works/  the blog example is using flask, I tried to make the script for people using django
Here is my media.py **( not sure if this works yet )**

**media.py**

```
import json
from goose import Goose

def extract(request):
    url = request.args.get('url')
    g = Goose()
    article = g.extract(url=url)
    resposne = {'image':article.top_image.src}
    return json.dumps(resposne)
```

How do I use the image I get from above and put it in a thumbnail and display that on the index.html ?  please, any help would be very appreciated. Merry Christmas

Edit 1 : I tried to convert below to django script but in my case  only script image

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from goose import Goose

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/api/v1/extract')
def extract():
    url = request.args.get('url')
    g = Goose()
    article = g.extract(url=url)
    response = {'title' : article.title , 'text' : article.cleaned_text[:250], 'image': article.top_image.src}
    return jsonify(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here.. is that a flask view? From what I can tell you're after a django tutorial which is off topic for SO. Merry Christmas though!

Comment: No this is django view, I'm asking how I can use the above function which extracts image to my app, so I can use the image to display the image to my index.html

Comment: Well thats not a valid view in django... is this supposed to be an ajax-called view?

Comment: @Sayse thanks for the response, no this is just meant to a function that extract image. I got inspiration from here, https://blog.openshift.com/day-16-goose-extractor-an-article-extractor-that-just-works/ ....did i do it wrong?

Comment: my plan was to write a method inside media.py and using that media.py script somewhere in my app(I'm asking where that somewhere is....at first I thought views.py but it seems like I'm missing something..

Comment: All Django views need to return some sort of http response. I'm not sure what answer I could provide that would be a valid solution to your problem  exactly.... as a starting point `return JsonResponse(status=200, data=resposne)` may be what you're looking for

Comment: @Sayse did I at least convert the above function right, I edited..

Comment: for the most part yes, Im not sure about the `request.args.get` bit... get parameters in django are stored in `request.GET` although I'm not sure what url you're after, I'd recommend looking at the django tutorial

Comment: I'm after url user provides

Comment: @Sayse how would you do it then?

Comment: I'd probably post a form that contains a text field with the url and then return whatever data needed. Django has `Form` classes that help with validation etc but all this would be too broad for a SO answer